# I can't decrease the height and width of hexagon shape element

Tags: html, css

I want to decrease the size of the hexagon shape element but I can't.

```css
.r-hex {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20em;
 height: 17.32em;
 transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
 border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.r-hex *,
.r-hex *::before {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 border-radius: inherit;
}

.r-hex-inner,
.r-hex-inner-2 {
 transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}

.r-hex-inner-2 {
 background: #2388ed;
 content: '';
}

.r-hex-inner-2::before {
 margin-top: -1.5em;
 width: 20em;
 height: 20em;
 transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(-90deg);
 background: url(https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687);
 background-size: cover;
 text-align: center;
 content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="r-hex">
       <div class="r-hex-inner">
        <div class="r-hex-inner-2"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

When I change the `20em` width and height I lose the radius of the shape.

So my question is how can decrease the size of the shape without damage it?

Comment: To what size do you want to decease it to? Once you change the width/height on the hexagon element, all the absolute units have to be scaled accordingly: e.g. if you decide the width should be halved to `10em`, then all the em values used should be halved, as well, to preserved the ratio.

Comment: @Terry yes I understand you and I have done that change 20em of all elements to 10em but the shape damged :( please can you try i think the problem in the trasnforms.

Comment: That means you must have left something out: if you change the width by a certain factor, all `em` units in the code snippet above need to be rescaled by the same factor. All the transforms are relative values (in degrees), so they should scale regardless of the size.

Comment: @Terry can you check the answer of TheoretiCAL and my comment on it? to understand me more.

Comment: His answer is incorrect because he forgot to scale the height accordingly (it shouldn't be `10em`), and he forgot to scale the marginTop values.

Comment: @Terry can you please add the correct answer to learn from you?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use CSS custom properties/variables, if you want to only support modern evergreen browsers. It makes life a lot easier for you because you only need to change the value of `--scale` to resize the hexagon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, if you want to change the width of the hexagon, all `em` values in your code snippet needs to be scaled accordingly. Let's say you want to make the new width `10em`. That gives you a scale factor of 0.5, because you are scaling from `20em` down to `10em` (i.e. half the size). Therefore, all absolute units (px, em, etc.) needs to be scaled by the same factor.

I've annotated in the code below where all the scaling needs to be done. The other answer in this thread happened to miss out some of the units, resulting in an incorrect appearance.

```css
.r-hex {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  
  /* Originally 20em, scaled by 0.5x */
  width: 10em;
  
  /* Originally 17.32em, scaled by 0.5x */
  height: 8.66em;
  
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
  
  /* Originally 10px, scaled by 0.5x */
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  /* Originally 2rem, scaled by 0.5x */
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.r-hex *,
.r-hex *::before {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.r-hex-inner,
.r-hex-inner-2 {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}

.r-hex-inner-2 {
  background: #2388ed;
  content: '';
}

.r-hex-inner-2::before {
  /* Originally -1.5em, scaled by 0.5x */
  margin-top: -0.75em;
  
  /* Originally 20em, scaled by 0.5x */
  width: 10em;
  
  /* Originally 20em, scaled by 0.5x */
  height: 10em;
  
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(-90deg);
  background: url(https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="r-hex">
  <div class="r-hex-inner">
    <div class="r-hex-inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Bonus: Use CSS custom property/variable to perform all the calculations for you

In fact, you can do all these calculations using JavaScript as well: nothing is impossible. Note that the example below uses CSS custom properties (also known as CSS variables) and only evergreen browsers support them so far (i.e. no IE11 support).

The trick is to simply convert all references to absolute units to be dependent on a `--scale` CSS variable and combining them with `calc()`. By changing this single CSS variable, you can effortlessly resize your hexagons without needing to worry about manually recalculating the values yourself:

```js
document.querySelector('#scale').addEventListener('input', e => {
  // Get the scale and convert it to a number
  const scale = +e.target.value;
  
  const hexElements = document.querySelectorAll('.r-hex');
  hexElements.forEach(hexElement => {
    hexElement.style.setProperty('--scale', scale);
  });
});
```

```css
.r-hex {
  /* This CSS property can be manipulated by JS */
  --scale: 1;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(20em * var(--scale));
  height: calc(17.32em * var(--scale));
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skewX(30deg);
  border-radius: calc(10px * var(--scale));
  margin-top: calc(2rem * var(--scale));
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

.r-hex *,
.r-hex *::before {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.r-hex-inner,
.r-hex-inner-2 {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(60deg) skewX(30deg);
}

.r-hex-inner-2 {
  background: #2388ed;
  content: '';
}

.r-hex-inner-2::before {
  margin-top: calc(-1.5em * var(--scale));
  width: calc(20em * var(--scale));
  height: calc(20em * var(--scale));
  transform: skewX(-30deg) rotate(-90deg);
  background: url(https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<label>Scale: <input type="number" value="1" step="0.1" min="0.1" id="scale"/></label>

<br />

<div class="r-hex">
  <div class="r-hex-inner">
    <div class="r-hex-inner-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```